# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0?

Tags: python

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0 
No matching distribution found for torch>=1.0.0 (from stanfordnlp)

Comment: The problem for me was a 32 bit installation of Python. I really could not find a way to install PyTorch on my 32 bit Python. I ended up removing it and installing 64-bit Python, and then I could install PyTorch.

Answer (score 152):

This can also happen if your Python version is too new. Pytorch currently [does not support past 3.7.9](https://pypi.org/project/torch/).

Figured out from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58902298/5090928

Comment: I was previously using `FROM python:3` which was giving error, I changed it to `FROM python:3.7` in my `Dockerfile` and it got fixed.

Comment: downgraded from 3.10.1 to 3.9.8 and it just worked. Thank you

Comment: As of now, Pytorch supports up to Python 3.9 which you can get here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3913/ and install with `py -3.9 -m pip install torch`

Comment: Download python exe from visiting https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/ and downloading zip  `Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file` then extract it to disk, create a virtual env by specifying the exe location using `virtualenv --python .\python379\python.exe env`, now activate it using `.\env\Scripts\activate` and you should be able to install.

Comment: This is so silly. Had to cave and use anaconda to manage my env + packages, and then it works even with (almost latest) python -- 3.10.x. (Haven't tried with 3.11.x, ran out of patience.)

Comment: `3.10.13` works well.

Comment: As of Dec.2023 (torch 2x), the latest supported Python version is 3.10. Figured this out experimentally. So please AVOID putting "FROM python:3" in your Dockerfile, put "FROM python:3.10" or "FROM python:3.9"

Answer (score 50):

This is the latest command for pytorch.

```
pip install torch===1.4.0 torchvision===0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 17):

I had some difficulties with this as well. The steps I had to do was:

Install the latest version of PyTorch:

```
 pip3 install torch===1.3.1 torchvision===0.4.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Make sure you are installing with 64bit python version; otherwise, it won't work

Comment: This answer works great, but the versions will need to be updated from the link provided by Ranjan [pytorch official website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). Essentially they are the same answer.

Answer (score 13):

I finally managed to solve this problem thanks to John Red' comment and serg06 answer. Here's what I've done :

1. Install Python **3.7.9** and not newer.
2. BUT make sure to install **64bits** python

Every other combination failed for me.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to install torch 2.1.0 into Python 3.12.0 and had this same error. It turns out torch doesn't like "the newest python on the block". Downgraded to python 3.11.1 and installation finished successfuly.

Comment: This answer does not add anything new to the currently available answers.

Comment: This worked for me too, downgrading to Python 3.11.6. Silly that Pytorch doesn't document the max Python version it supports.

Comment: Very useful answer, as it's updated to late 2023.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue while installing standfordnlp in my windows 10 system.
Installing torch before installing stanfordnlp worked out for me.
I have installed torch from [pytorch official website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Answer (score 5):

For people visiting this questions with slightly newer versions of python and pytorch, I had *Python 3.8.3 32-bit* and even though the pytorch page states that:

> Currently, PyTorch on Windows only supports Python 3.7-3.9;

Installing *Python 3.9.13 64-bit* instead of *Python 3.8.3 32-bit* solved it for me.
After that, I used the [install script generator](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and ran
`python -m pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113`
... and it started downloading.

Answer (score 4):

Use 64-Bit Python. PyTorch doesn't work with 32-Bit Python. I had the same issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32366022)

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas yes it does, it is helpful and helps answer the question of knowing how to install torch on windows.

Answer (score 4):

Running Apple Silicon M3 Pro the only way that worked for me was to load the nightly build as recommended by [Apple Developers website](https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/):

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

It is expected to work with conda as well (Recommended way)

Comment: This also worked for me on Windows, as my Python version was too new.

Answer (score 3):

If you have python 3.7 already installed along with newer versions then can use below command to install torch using python 3.7

```
py -3.7 -m pip install torch
```

But also note that you have to execute the python program using py -3.7

```
py -3.7 program_name.py
```

Comment: very useful answer. I work with Visual Studio, I changed the version and type this command and "voila"...  i get torch

Answer (score 2):

I went heaven and earth for this problem and here is what it turned out to be:

1- i had python 3.10
2- the python.exe in my virtual environemnt linked to python310

i uninstalled the python3.10 , then went to delete the paths in system environemnts variables (go to windows search, type this thing, you get a window, click on environment variables, and find a word called paths, click edit) ....\python310\ (i named as such when initially installed, you probs have another name) and also this ...python310\Scripts\

delete them

go to https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3711/ , istall pythion 3.7 , after that go back to system env. variables thingy, .. add the paths that ends with ...\python37\ , and ...\python37\Scripts\ (make you sure you end the paths with "")

then go to new command prompt, type python , you should get Python 3.7.0 ...

cd to your virtual environment path script (mine looked like this C:\Users...\python_ver\python_projects\root_environment\Scripts>) , activate to the name of whatever you called, for me i typed: activate tf.

type python again, if you have python 3.7 as a result, you good to go ... if you still seeing python 3.10 ... then you probs get some error saying no python in ....\python310\python.exe ... so:

go the folder that you saved python310 (the path shown in the last step), make sure all folders of your python 3.7 go in there.

type python in cmd in the same virtual envrioment path by the cursor ... to check you running pythong 3.7 ...

once python 3.7 is your default .. run the blood Clot for pytorch https://pytorch.org/ to install pytorch

thanks to all the guys on this

Answer (score 1):

torch and torchvision need python 3.8.x ... so in your CLI run

```
python --version
```

to get the python version.
make sure that your environment has python 3.8.x, otherwise, create another virtual environment with anaconda

```
conda create -n myenv python==3.8 anaconda
conda activate myenv
```

Then install torch and torchvision by this command

```
pip install torch===1.5.0 torchvision===0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue with python3.12. So, I need to downgrade it to python3.11

```
brew uninstall python

brew install python@3.11

pip install torch===2.1.0 torchvision===0.16.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This works fine for me in MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every possible command for Windows, but nothing worked. I also tried using Pycharm package installation, everything throws the same error.

Finally installed Pytorch using Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I want to `pip install  " torch>=1.4.0,  torchvision>=0.5.0 "`,  but in a conda env with python=3.0, this is not right.
I tried create a new conda env with python=3.7, and `pip install  " torch>=1.4.0,  torchvision>=0.5.0 "` again, it is ok.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For previous versions please use the snippets from the PyTorch website; https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

As an example, this will turn into an error since the cudatoolkit versions are not listed in pip;

```
!pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.10.0+cu111 (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.10.0+cu111

For the same Torch version and cudatoolkit, **you can use the following code instead**;

```
!pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.10.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

---

```
import torch
TORCH_VERSION = ".".join(torch.__version__.split(".")[:2])
CUDA_VERSION = torch.__version__.split("+")[-1]
print("torch: ", TORCH_VERSION, "; cuda: ", CUDA_VERSION)
```

> **Result:**

```
torch:  1.10 ; cuda:  cu111
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Deep Reinforcement Learning: Chapter-6: 02_dnq_pong.py:
I did not verify the above solutions. I found it tedious to change the existing library version.

So, as mentioned by someone in GIT, you just have to change two variables in your loss function.
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/issues/90

Change the variables to below:
actions_v = torch.tensor(actions).to(device, dtype=torch.int64)
done_mask = torch.tensor(dones).to(device, dtype=torch.bool)

You could make similar changes to the variables which cause the error, in your respective programs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Python 3.8.2 which is currently supported by PyTorch. I updated `pip` from version 19.2.3 to 22.3.1 and my issue was solved:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual environment with Python 3.7.9

Go to the python version download page (with binary installers) https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/

Go to that page and download `Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file`
extracted the zip file and placed the contents inside the project folder.

Then used,

```
virtualenv --python .\python379\python.exe env
```

To create the virtual environment by specifying the exe location.

Now activate it using `.\env\Scripts\activate` and you should be able to install.

> If you get any error like `virtualenv: The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,` uninstall `virtualenv` using `pip uninstall virtualenv`, close the terminal, open terminal as
> Administrator / root user and install again.

Answer (score 0):

i have installed with python 3.9 version by running below commands:

py -3.9 -m pip install torch

Answer (score 0):

I did follow many suggestions in this thread by installing python 3.7 and python 3.9 ( the one I have by default on my machine is 3.11). The only thing that worked for me is to install the 3.8 version using pyenv and install pytorch from there. Here is the code :

```
# install python 3.8
pyenv install 3.8

# switch to python 3.8
pyenv shell 3.8

# install pytorch
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I am using Python 3.6 and I ran this command it works

```
pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue:
try to check if you have any issues with `apt_pkg`,

- Before downgrading to a lower version, try this command `sudo apt install --reinstall python3 python python3-minimal --fix-broken`

In my case: I have Python 3.12, error was with apt_pkg

Answer (score -6):

follow the link: https://pytorch.org/

and set your system requirement in QUICK START LOCALLY SECTION

[image]