# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement standfordnlp (from versions: )

Tags: python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement standfordnlp (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for standfordnlp

I tried to install pytorch and then install standfordnlp ( as suggested here : [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239310/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-0-0) ), however the problem seems to persist.

Comment: let us know your python version, if you are using python in anaconda environment then upgrade all and then try.

Comment: Python version is 3.7.3. Have updated anaconda environment. Still the same error.

Comment: upgrade conda, anaconda & spyder by using `conda upgrade conda` , `conda upgrade anaconda` & `conda upgrade spyder`  on anaconda prompt, restart the anaconda and then try to install your library.

Comment: I forgot to restart anaconda. After updating and restart, I installed the package and it worked.