# Issues installing PyTorch 1.4 - "No matching distribution found for torch===1.4.0"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, pytorch

Used the install guide on `pytorch.org` on how to install it and the command I'm using is

```
pip install torch===1.4.0 torchvision===0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

But it's coming up with this error;

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.4.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch===1.4.0

Is this even a me-related issue? Can other people use this command?

Pip is installed and works for other modules, Python 3.8, CUDA version 10.1, Windows 10 Home 2004

Comment: Maybe add the full output of the command, there might be something meaningful in there.

Comment: can one not have torch be installed inside the setup.py file when installing my projects i.e. me not having to run pip install torch etc etc?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like this issue is related to virtual environment. Did you try recommended installation line in another/new one virtual environment? If it doesn't help the possible solution might be installing package using direct link to PyTorch and TorchVision builds for your system:

**Windows:**

```bash
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torchvision-0.5.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

**Ubuntu (Linux):**

```bash
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.4.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl

pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torchvision-0.5.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: i had to -f it like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59920239/2062726

Comment: can one not have torch be installed inside the setup.py file when installing my projects i.e. me not having to run pip install torch etc etc?

Comment: what about macos??

Answer (score 22):

In the future, I would recommend using the installation widget on the PyTorch website.

It fixed this issue for me by extending the command with `-f` as follows:

`pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Comment: Thanks William! If I want to included it in requirements.txt how can I include url part?

Comment: can one not have torch be installed inside the setup.py file when installing my projects i.e. me not having to run pip install torch etc etc?

Comment: @haneulkim hmm... I'm not sure how the URL can be included in requirements.txt

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem and `python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` worked for me and https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/ may be useful for some package installation problems.

Answer (score 9):

check your python version, my version is python 3.8.2 and it can't find a torch version matched the py version. And I use a 3.7.6 now, I suppose the version below 3.8 would be fine

Comment: 2023 update if you try to install in Docker (CPU) , image that worked for me was `python:3.8.17-slim` after a `RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`, command to install torch was taken from official website => `RUN pip install torch torchvision --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`

Answer (score 7):

I tried pip, only got it working with conda

```
conda install pytorch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

Comment: Is Conda preferable over Pip?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old one, but it came up when searching for today's problems upgrading torch to 1.12.0. Same kinds of error messages, none of these or other proposals helped. What did help was upgrading pip (now 22.1.2), I was behind a minor release and had been ignoring that. Everything just worked after that.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was the Python version I was using was unsupported. I was trying to install torch 1.10.0 on Python 3.10.6 which was giving me the same error. Solution was to downgrade Python to 3.8.x

Answer (score 2):

I also had same problem as a comment up and I decieded it so

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

@Collin TNX!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the right solution that could solve this issue:

Reinstall pytorch from here:
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#mac-package-manager

Make sure the torch version is 1.4.0 if it's not run the following command:

pip install syft -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Now, you can download syft successfully:

pip install syft

to check the version of packages:
conda list

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to build image for linux architecture and after I change docker command it worked:

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t rahul86s/rsharmp12_model:latest .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. For me the only Nightly version worked.
You can install it with

`pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu117`

Answer (score -1):

It could be a syntax issue, because you are using `===` instead of `==` in your `pip install` command.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, its reason was related compiled version (32/64) I have installed a 32bit version but PyTorch's wheel only provides a 64bit version.

No problem on your command check python version and reinstall the 64bit version.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue, according to https://pytorch.org/ the best option is to install everything via conda:

conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch