# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch~=1.4.0 (from syft) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)

Tags: python, pytorch, pysyft

I get the above error while installing **syft** package through Anaconda command. I followed the below link exactly as is, 
https://medium.com/secure-and-private-ai-writing-challenge/installing-pysyft-package-ffa1ff0ad83c

Following commands were used:

```
conda create -n pysyft python=3
conda activate pysyft
pip install syft
```

Some of the links suggested to update the Pytorch version. I have 1.5.0+cpu version already and updating didnt help. I also tried using `pip install syft` without creating a conda environment, that didnt solve the problem either. 
I went through the below stackoverflow link too which explains similar error, but it didnt help either: 
[Issues installing PyTorch 1.4 - "No matching distribution found for torch===1.4.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137572/issues-installing-pytorch-1-4-no-matching-distribution-found-for-torch-1-4)

Any advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try installing it with `pip install syft -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`? Otherwise, could you install PyTorch *1.4.0* manually (not *1.5.0*, that's not supported by syft)?

Comment: thanks Micheal... the first command worked, just that I had to use "--user" after "install". I think your comment must be an answer for this question............  pip install --user syft -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all PyTorch versions are available on Python's package registry PyPI. For instance, the CPU only version or any Windows version is only available on PyTorch's custom registry. Selecting one of these versions on [PyTorch - Get Started Locally](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) will give you an installation command including the custom registry. Installing PySyft also installs PyTorch and the specific version you're getting, requires adding the custom registry:

```
pip install syft -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

You might need to add `--user` if you don't have write access to the system wide package location.

Comment: Are there any reason why this isn't in the official documentation if this is the expected way to install syft?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment and use `pip install syft==0.2.9`.

It will also install a compatible pytorch for you.