# Can't install pytorch: no matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0+cpu

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

When trying to install PyTorch, I can't progress past these errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0+cpu
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239310/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-0-0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22No+matching+distribution+found+for+torch%3D%3D1.7.0%2Bcpu%22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue likely has to do with your Python version. PyTorch will not work with the 32-bit version of Python, so if you're using 32-bit it will give that error. I had this happen to me before, switching to 64-bit should fix the error.