# Issue installing Facebook NeuralProphet

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to install NeuralProphet via Anaconda Prompt (Acnadconda3), however I'm getting the following errors:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch<1.7.0,>=1.4.0 (from neuralprophet) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch<1.7.0,>=1.4.0 (from neuralprophet)`

I've checked my version of python (as below) from what I can see it's running 64bit - so I don't think this is the issue? Any help would be greately apprecaited!

````
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32```
````

Comment: This might be able to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239310/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-0-0

Comment: Which command did you run?

Comment: Thanks for the responses - it turn's out Adam was right, I needed to downgrade the version of Pytorch so it would work - I ended up installing 1.6 using the below command in Anaconda prompt and I am now able to install NeuralProphet :) 

`conda install pytorch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the version of PyTorch in this link ([Previous PyTorch version](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)).

Example:
`

## CUDA 9.2

```
conda install pytorch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0 cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch
```

## CUDA 10.1

```
conda install pytorch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

## CPU Only

```
conda install pytorch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0 cpuonly -c pytorch
```