# I don't know how to install Pytorch

Tags: python

I don't know how to install Pytorch with pip on windows. No commands I do will work.
I tried:

> pip install torch
>
> pip3 install torch
>
> pip install pytorch
>
> pip3 install pytorch
>
> pip install torch torchvisual torchaudio
>
> pip3 install torch torchvisual torchaudio
>
> pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cu102 torchvision==0.11.2+cu102
> torchaudio===0.10.1+cu102 -f
> https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch_stable.html

and I used the website to try and install it but they all have this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Comment: This might sound simple but do you have python installed?

Comment: What is the error for `pip3 install torch`?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/torch/ `pip install torch`

Comment: pip install torch should work

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: This question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239310/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-0-0. Have you tried the things this post recommends?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239310/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-0-0)

Answer (score 5):

You probably tried this on Python 3.10, there isn't a build for PyTorch on PyPI for 3.10 yet. Just install Python 3.9 for the time being and you'll be fine with `pip install torch`.

(note, this was posted on 2021-12-25; hello people from the future, it seems likely that this won't last too long, so your problem may be a different one)

Comment: FWIW, pytorch is not compatible with 3.11.1 despite what the docs say, so this issue stills applies today. (At least, it isn't compatible on macOS. Might be on other OSs).

Answer (score 0):

You can install `torch` for `python 3.7` to `3.9` using [this page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/). I have tried installing `torch` for `python V3.11,3.10`, but failed. If you do not have a GPU, use [this link](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).