# Not able to install Torch package in the python locally

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not able to install the torch package in Python with this command
`pip install torch`

but this command works well in the Anaconda shell.
I tried various commands available on the net, but I am still getting the same error as below.

*Getting this error*
`pip install torch`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: This is the Version Python 3.12.0

Comment: I think it might be your python version. can you try creating a new environment, install python 3.9 in that environment and try again?

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your Python version is too new. Pytorch currently does not support past 3.7.9. I found at [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239310/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-0-0) !